# how to check if hadoop-common.jar and hadoop-aws.jar are in sync?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have a newly installed hadoop2.8 for spark2.2.1. It throws `spark java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100M"` when I enter pyspark.

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149929/hive-1-2-metastore-service-doesnt-start-after-configuring-it-to-s3-storage-inst) question for my solution .

Additional Info: I am trying to create spark sessions with AWS ARN roles to that spark can access different data sources with **Assume role** capability in AWS.

Edit: Installed hadoop2.8 for spark2.2.1; Previously had hadoop2.7 as a default but it doesn't support aws roles for spark sessions.

Comment: What Hadoop versions you have? Did you configure the same version with AWS?

Comment: I Just installed hadoop 2.8.3. The here are the versions : `hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` and `hadoop-common-2.8.3.jar`

Comment: That is the problem. Match the versions.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see that error message anyone, but it gives a pile of new once to match multiple jar versions. The latest one is ` An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AmazonS3Exception`

Comment: What version you are pointing AWS to?

Comment: here is the AWS CLI version `aws-cli/1.15.80` and the jar `aws-java-sdk-1.10.6.jar`

Comment: The problem was in the Hadoop Version I had installed, I was working with it before but after changing to S3 I thought it wasn't used anymore, but Hive needs it. I have took your advice and I have started playing with the source code. Thanks. :)

Comment: Read the above comment. It is referencing to the SO page.

Comment: Resolved the issue, We were missing `aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.366.jar` file. Thanks for the quick responses Prazy!!

Comment: Glad! It worked. You are welcome.